# When is the Fermat Catalan surface a rational surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

Related to [Fermat Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat-Catalan_conjecture) and scholar.google.com didn't return any results.

Define the [Fermat Catalan surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat-Catalan_conjecture)

$$ S_{m,n,k}: x^m+y^n=z^k$$

Where $\frac1m+\frac1n+\frac1k < 1$.

> Q1 When is $S_{m,n,k}$ rational surface?

(Limited experiments in magma online didn't find counterexamples
when $\gcd(m,n,k)=1$).

Rational for m,n,k=(3,3,5),(2,4,5),(4,4,5)

If someone has unlimited access to magma, it may be a good idea
to do longer computations.

[Magma online code](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

```
 Q := RationalField();
 P<x,y,z> := PolynomialRing(Q, 3);
 F<s,t> := RationalFunctionField(Q, 2);
 p := x^2+y^4-z^5;
 Solve(p, F);
```